# How public DNS works?

Tags: dns, domain, domain-name, google-public-dns, domain-security

If I have a small enterprise network with some web servers and a DNS with DNSSEC for signing the zone file. I can edit the zone file and configure the mapping (name -> IP) in addition to any other mappings, e.g. TXT records, etc. then sign the file. A DNSSEC supported client queries the DNS and gets the records, verifies the signature, etc.

If my users use public DNS like 8.8.8.8, how can I configure my own DNS TXT records there. Is a public DNS like 8.8.8.8 is a DNS server or just resolver? How public DNS works exactly to resolve `example.com` that uses DNSSEC to authenticate in its DNS server? who has the signing keys? `example.com` or the public DNS?

Comment: There is a disconnect between your knowledge, question and setup. Clearly someone had the skill to set this up - you should work with them.

Comment: @davidgo I did the setup for private network for learning purposes. I have understanding of how things work in the private network. But I need to get further insight into how things work when a user or a client uses public DNS given the fact that the enterprise has signed their DNS records. In this case, the client validate the response using which public key? the enterprise's server or the public DNS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is a public DNS like 8.8.8.8 is a DNS server or just resolver?

It's just a resolver like those provided by ISPs. It does not change *anything* about how your domain is managed: the records are still kept in the zonefile in your 'authoritative' servers, and you sign the zone with your own keys.

> If my users use public DNS like 8.8.8.8, how can I configure my own DNS TXT records there.

You don't. Since 8.8.8.8 is a resolver, it will follow the chain of delegations (NS records) and will get the records from *your own* authoritative server. (Exactly the same way as resolving other domains like "google.com"...)

So if the domain is public (bought from a registrar) and if your DNS server is publicly accessible, then nothing will change.

Of course, if the domain *isn't* delegated – e.g. if it's under some made-up TLD like `mycompany.lan` – then public resolvers won't be able to see it *at all.* So don't use made-up domains.

> How public DNS works exactly to resolve example.com that uses DNSSEC to authenticate in its DNS server

For regular DNS record retrieval, see above, and see plenty of existing documentation. In short, the resolver follows the chain of NS records from the root zone until it finds your own server.

DNSSEC validation is very similar: in addition to NS records (pointing to the next server), each delegation also has DS records (having the next zone's public key). The resolver or validator again follows the chain of DS records.

Comment: So can I say the domain owner is the same entity that has the DNS signing keys? i.e. `example.com` owner is the same entity that has the signing keys for the DNS records of `example.com`?

Comment: That's often the case, yes. But not always: many people don't run their own authoritative servers, and simply use the registrar's free web-based "DNS control panel" service. In that case, the zone file is generated and signed (or not) by the registrar, not by the owner.

Comment: (Which is still an "authoritative server" service, and completely unrelated to public resolvers like Google Public DNS.)